# If statement not working - copying individual rows to a different sheet if there is a specific value in that row

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy-paste, autofilter

I've been struggling for a while with this:
I'm trying to write a script that copies over a whole row from a sheet called 'search' into a sheet called 'order' at the click of a button. Based on if there is a value entered into that row in column M.

I have written the if statement so that it pulls the rows over that have a value bigger than 0.

However - it always pulls in ONLY the top lines of the 'search' source database - never the ones that have a value in.

The data in the source are all formulas - could this be an issue? Otherwise is there a way to copy and paste data as values?

For instance - in the below picture I want to pull over ID 1359399 and 1359403. But it will always pull over the top two lines (1359394 and 1359395).

[image]

Thanks for any help.

```
Sub CopySomeCells()
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
Dim SourceRow As Long
Dim DestinationRow As Long

Set SourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search")
Set DestinationSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Order")

DestinationRow = DestinationSheet.Cells(DestinationSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For SourceRow = 2 To SourceSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If SourceSheet.Range("M" & SourceRow).Value > 0 Then
        SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(SourceRow, 1), SourceSheet.Cells(SourceRow, 29)).Copy _
            DestinationSheet.Cells(DestinationRow, 2)
        DestinationRow = DestinationRow + 1
    End If
Next SourceRow
Range("M2:M7000").Clear
```

End Sub

Comment: Is the problem with the detection of the row?  Or with the copy/paste operation?  Put a breakpoint on the line after your `If` and examine the values if/when it breaks.  Since your top lines appear to have no value in the relevant column, I'd think there might be problem with your detection algorithm.

Comment: Ah yes! I've just done that - the breakpoint shows that it is the correct data at that point. I think this means that it is down to the formula being pulled across and not the values. Do you know if there's a way to copy data as values only instead of a full copy paste?

Comment: But you said those lines were not being copied **at all**.  You can use the `PasteSpecial` method to paste only values, but I don't see how that would prevent the line from being copied at all.  Maybe you've got a wrong reference.  Any `On Error` statements you aren't showing? Perhaps you should change `ActiveWorkbook` references to `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: The formula for the data in the source sheet is indexing a query, line by line. So it appears to be identifying the correct lines, but when they're pasted in the destination - it is changing the line references to line 1, line 2 etc, even though in the source they are e.g. line 11, ,line 14. What is the paste special method?

Comment: What about that method is not understandable when you check VBA help files?

Comment: Apologies - I probably understated my novice abilities! Where are VBA help files? I'll have a look and see if I can change the copy function to a paste special.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Criteria Rows Using AutoFilter

- Copies rows of data that meet a criterion in a column, to another worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopySomeRows()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Search"
    Const sCol As Long = 13 ' M
    Const sCriteria As String = ">0" ' or "<>" for not blank, ' or "=" for blank
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Order"
    Const dfCol As Long = 2 ' B
    ' Both
    Const cCount As Long = 29
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim strg As Range ' Source Table Range (headers)
    Set strg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, cCount)
    If strg.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data or just headers
    Dim sdrg As Range ' Source Data Range (no headers)
    Set sdrg = strg.Resize(strg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    strg.AutoFilter sCol, sCriteria
    
    Dim sdvrg As Range ' Source Data Visible Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sdvrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dfCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    If Not sdvrg Is Nothing Then
        sdvrg.Copy
        dfCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        dws.Activate
        dfCell.Select
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False ' the next line does the job
        sdrg.Columns(sCol).ClearContents ' or .Clear
        'sws.Activate
        MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No data found.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub
```